# IntegrityError when calling get_or_create() on a nested object in Django REST

Tags: django, nested, serialization

The following problem is driving me real crazy ...

I have three models:

- Order
- Target
- ConstructionSite

An Order has a "date" and "users" and a lot of "targets". The Target itself consists of some information and a key to a "ConstructionSite".

I'm trying to build a RESTful API with Angular. So far so good. I also know that writable nested serializers have to be build manually.

**My Models:**

```
class ConstructionSite(models.Model):
    cost_unit_nr = models.CharField(primary_key=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField("Datum")
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class Target(models.Model):
    cost_unit_nr = models.OneToOneField(ConstructionSite)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name="targets")
```

**My Serializers***

```
class ConstructionSiteIDSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    cost_unit_nr = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = ConstructionSite
        fields = ('cost_unit_nr',)

class TargetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cost_unit_nr = ConstructionSiteIDSerializer()
    id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Target
        fields = ('id', 'cost_unit_nr', 'services', 'sequence_number', 'published')


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users   = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), many=True)
    targets = TargetSerializer(many=True, required=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'date', 'targets', 'users')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        targets_data = validated_data.pop('targets')
        users_data = validated_data.pop('users')

        instance.date = validated_data.get('date', instance.date)

        # User handling ... (not shown here)

        # Targets
        instance.targets = []

        for target in targets_data:
            cs_data = target.get('cost_unit_nr')

            new_target, created = Target.objects.update_or_create(id=target.get('id', False))

            cs_instance, created = ConstructionSite.objects.get_or_create(cost_unit_nr=cs_data.get('cost_unit_nr'))

            new_target.cost_unit_nr = cs_instance
            new_target.services = target.get('services')
            new_target.published = target.get('published', False)
            new_target.sequence_number = target.get('sequence_number', 0)

            instance.targets.add(new_target)


        instance.save()

        return instance
```

**Data**

I'm trying to update an existing Order. It already has a Target and I want to add another one:

```
[{"id":13,
  "date":"2015-12-03",
  "targets":[
      {
      "id":15,
      "cost_unit_nr": "cost_unit_nr":"3"},
      "services":"whatever",
      "sequence_number":0, 
      "published":false},
      {
      "cost_unit_nr": "cost_unit_nr":"4"},
      "services":"still whatever",
      "sequence_number":0, 
      "published":false}],
  "users":[1]}]
```

cost_unit_nr is the id of the ConstructionSite object.

The 2nd entry of targets has no ID of course, it should be created when I call update_or_create ... But an IntegrityError is thrown:

```
('weekplans_target.cost_unit_nr_id may not be NULL',)
```

Where "weekplans" is the name of my app.

First: why?
Second: why target.cost_unit_nr_id? I don't have this field anywhere. Why is _id added to cost_unit_nr

Thanks guys!

Comment: The `_id` is the PK that django creates implicitly. All relationships like FK, m2m, OneToOne would by default be linked by the underlying id unless any PK is explicitly specified.

Comment: Your error is basically saying you didn't specify the id to build the `OneToOne` relationship. I'm not sure how your `update_or_create` works, but you might need to create a target first and get the id.